# Checking if a day is the same day (but not year) with momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I'm using `momentjs` to determine wether or not a date is a persons birthday. But for some reason `moment` always returns `false` and I'm not sure why.

**Used code**

```
moment(dateObject).isSame(moment(otherDateObject), 'day')
```

**What is returned when logging the individual dates and the `isSame()`**

[image]

Any ideas on what the issue is here? As you can see the only difference in the 2 moment instances is the year.

**From momentjs**

> Passing in day will check day, month, and year

So how do I check if it is the matching day and month then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check only day of the month and the month, you can write your own function using [`date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) and [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) getters.

Here a sample:

```js
var m1 = moment('2017-01-25');
var m2 = moment('2015-02-25');
var m3 = moment('2015-02-25');

function isSameDayAndMonth(m1, m2){
  return m1.date() === m2 .date() && m1.month() === m2.month()
}

console.log( isSameDayAndMonth(m1, m2) );
console.log( isSameDayAndMonth(m1, m3) );
console.log( isSameDayAndMonth(m2, m3) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the days are considered different as they fall in different years and are not the same day.

From https://momentjs.com/docs/:

```
moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2010-02-01', 'day');   // false, different month
```

I would try something like this if you only want to check if the day is the same:

```
if (moment(dateObject, "D") === moment(otherDateObject, "D"))
```

You can use "E" for the day of week...